# Git strategy for holding docker configurations for multiple machines

Tags: linux, git, docker

I have a number of docker hosts - for arguments sake lets use 3 as an example.   On those 3 hosts I have a total of 10 applications.  Each will be standalone, or part of a stack.   Most of the applications do hold some persistent data (configuration files and the like).

I have in the past, used a flat svn structure.

```
docker-data
  stack1
    app1
    app2
    app3
  stack2
    app4
    app5
  stack3
   app6
   app7
  app8
  app9
```

The whole structure and the config files would be under svn and loaded on all 3 hosts.   Having to remember which host had which apps, and make changes and commit as needed.

Where host 1 = stack 1, host 2 = stack2, host3 = stack3 and app8 and 9

As part of rebuilding I was going to look at moving to git and a better structure.

I did see someone suggest the my entire structure go into git as the master
With a branch for each host.

```
master
  docker-data
    stack1
      app1
      app2
      app3
    stack2
      app4
      app5
    stack3
      app6
      app7
    app8
    app9
host1
   docker-data
    stack1
      app1
      app2
      app3
```

This seemed quite a good approach.  But what struck me is how to set it up initially.

If all my apps are in the master how do I initialise the branch for host one and only pull app1, 2 and 3?

I assume I them do a merge back to master if any of those configurations change.

And finally, I want to move app8 into host1's branch from host 3.

Is this over complicated? and are there any posts, or commands that would help me facilitate this?

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's not a good idea to use different Git branches for configuration on different systems because you run into problems like you've encountered. If you do this, you'll also likely run into conflicts if you need to do any merging.

The typical way that one manages configuration for different systems is a templating system of some sort. For example, you could use Ruby's ERB to write templates, and then configure each host with a YAML configuration file, with a build step producing an output directory with the configurations for each host. You will have just one main branch, with additional feature branches that get merged in as they're ready.

This approach is similar to the way that other configuration systems like Puppet and Ansible are designed to work, and it is generally much more robust than using separate branches for separate configurations.